# PDO and openssl_public_decrypt failing

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo, php-openssl

I am trying to decrypt and update password into a mysql database table. while doing it is giving me a weird error.

> PHP Warning:  PDO::exec(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>   in
>   .../vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php
>   on line 306 PHP Warning:  PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   .../vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php
>   on line 306 PHP Warning:  PDO::exec(): Error reading result set's
>   header in
>   ../vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php
>   on line 306

- passwords are encrypted using private key.

  - openssl_private_encrypt function is used for encryption.
- decryption is done using openssl_public_decrypt
- encryption along with insertion into databse works fine
- decryption along with update does not work. PDO::exec fails for some
  reason
- Platform i am using is Ubuntu, PHP 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
- Encrypt-Insert, Decrypt-Update is the order of operations.
- Mysql connection is open before encryption and decryption is performed

code for encryption decryption:

```
 function processPlainText($plainText, $action) {
        $cryptText = '';
        $res = 'encrypt' == $action ? openssl_get_privatekey($this->keyContents) : openssl_get_publickey($this->keyContents);
        $action = 'encrypt' == $action ? 'openssl_private_' . $action : 'openssl_public_'.$action;

        $action($plainText, $cryptText, $res);
        openssl_free_key($res);
        return $cryptText;
    }
```

Any insight on this problem would be much appreciated.

Code that works:

```
$pdo = getMysqlPdoInstance(); //get pdo instance using ssl
$id = 101;
$plainText = 'abcd';
$password = processPlainText($plainText, 'encrypt');
$count = $pdo->exec(sprintf("UPDATE table set password =  '%s' WHERE id = %d", $password, $id));
print("Updated $count rows.\n");
```

Code that fails:

```
$pdo = getMysqlPdoInstance(); //get pdo instance using ssl
$id = 101;
$password = processPlainText($encryptedPassword, 'decrypt');
$count = $pdo->exec(sprintf("UPDATE table set password =  '%s' WHERE id = %d", $password, $id));
print("Updated $count rows.\n");
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using public/private key encryption? Passwords should not be encrypted, the is insecure. Instead with PHP use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: You are true but these passwords are smtp passwords i am encrypting them and saving in to the database. what do you suggest for this use case?

Comment: I am curious why you chose asymmetric (public/private key pair) encryption, just consider this a survey.

Comment: If you must encrypt use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) with a random IV and encryption authentication with a random key. One uses asymmetric encryption when one needs a public/private key pair.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is a sort of experiment with openssl api i am doing. In fact i am using AES to encrypt those  passwords. But I still want to know why that operation failed. I suspect PDO in some way is facing problem when openssl_public_decrypt is used for a different purpose.

Comment: I don't think it's common to encrypt passwords - that implies they can be decrypted. The general standard is to hash them and assume you'll never need to decrypt them.

Comment: Thanks but How do you use a hashed smtp password? i dont think any email server supports that.

Comment: @sdhakal Since the error message says *"MySQL server has gone away"*, I doubt this has something to do with the encryption. Please [edit] your question to show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Start here: *`error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line ...`* - Please post your public key (or a public key that produces the same error). You should be able to `cat` it since its PEM format.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have included example that works and one that fails.

Comment: @jww : its not related to key, i have already verified that.  if i dont decrypt the password or if and don't run PDO::exec the code works fine. if i do both it fails. see my code example that fails.

Comment: Since the only difference is `$password` hex dump `$password` to see the difference, add that to the question. How is `password` defined in MySQL?

Comment: Note that encryption is done with the public key and decryption with the private key. Nut probably what you really want is symmetric encryption such as AES where booth the encryption and decryption is doe with the same key.

Answer (score 3):

Using SSL for the Mysql connection made you hit a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69524), resolved with a [patch](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/519b0dc886aed287e5c3472df9c879186f5112c2) ("openssl_decrypt triggers bug in PDO") to PHP 7.1, with no backports yet. In the last comment at the time of writing, instructions to a workaround can be found:

> .. please call openssl_error_string() after openssl_pkey_get_public in your app / script.

in your function, place `while(openssl_error_string() !== false);` above openssl_free_key() if you cannot move to PHP7.1.

In your comments you suspected properly, that *"PDO in some way is facing [a] problem when openssl_public_decrypt is used.."*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19189708)

Comment: I reproduced the issue with op's code - and it's mitigated by the aforementioned workaround.

Comment: if you're curious, see this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PLqTV9DC). As more people will use ssl for mysql because of cloud services, and an EOL date of 7.0 in Dec'18, there is a likelihood until then for users searching with the error message