# PHP problems combining MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL and openssl_pkey_new()

Tags: php, mysqli, openssl

I've been having strange openssl issues when combining a mysqli connection  (using SSL) together with openssl_*() functions within a PHP file.

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->real_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database', null, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

$keys = openssl_pkey_new();
$db->query("INSERT ...."); // <- errors occur here
```

If I'm not generating a key, or if I'm not inserting into the db, or if I'm not using MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL when connecting to the database, there are no issues. It's only when combining mysqli SSL and some other PHP openssl function that I get these errors:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in file.php     on line 107
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in file.php on line 107
Error: 108: MySQL server has gone away
```

And the INSERT statement fails.

This is the contents of /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf (default Debian Stretch):

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
oid_section     = new_oids
[ new_oids ]
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7
[ ca ]
[ CA_default ]
policy      = policy_match
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
string_mask = utf8only
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2
stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State
localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64
emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64
[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20
unstructuredName        = An optional company name
[ usr_cert ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
[ crl_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always
[ proxy_cert_ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo
[ tsa ]
[ tsa_config1 ]
```

I've extensively searched the internet to find a common scenario. Not sure where to look next. Maybe someone on Stackoverflow can point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Ah apparently I've hit a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69524) in PHP 7.0. It was solved by repeatingly calling `openssl_error_string()` right after using the openssl_* methods.

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->real_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database', null, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

$keys = openssl_pkey_new();
while (openssl_error_string() !== false);

$db->query("INSERT ...."); // <- no more errors occur here!
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419242/3964328

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify array parameter to openssl_pkey_new();
with 'config' key and value is your openssl configuration file.

So it's should like:
openssl_pkey_new(array('config'=>'/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf'));